# Boto3 : encryption of EBS IAM requirements

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create an EBS encrypted volume. If I keep encryption as False, it works as expected, when I turn it to True, a response with Http header 200 is returned, I get everything on my python console, but in reality the volume doesn't get created.

I think I lack IAM policies, what could be the required policies as I am not going to get IAM Full Access.

This is the response

> {u'AvailabilityZone': 'ap-south-1a', 'ResponseMetadata':
>   {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId':
>   '1c51475f-592c-4d78-bc31-242132b820ae', 'HTTPHeaders':
>   {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server':
>   'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri,
>   28 Apr 2017 07:09:38 GMT'}}, u'Encrypted': True, u'VolumeType':
>   'standard', u'VolumeId': 'vol-0fbbd415077636557', u'State':
>   'creating', u'SnapshotId': '', u'CreateTime': datetime.datetime(2017,
>   4, 28, 7, 9, 38, 612000, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'Size': 1}

If Encrypted=False, it works fine
[image: If Encrypted=False, it works fine]

Answer (score 0):

You are most probably attempting to create an encrypted volume from an unencrypted snapshot.

The [create_volume() documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_volume) says:

> Volumes that are created from encrypted snapshots are automatically encrypted. **There is no way to create an encrypted volume from an unencrypted snapshot or vice versa.**

Comment: I am not using snapshots at all. I am creating a blank volume.

Comment: Then why does your code contain `SnapshotId=snapshot_id`? Is it set to `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the **role** or **user** (using which you are trying to make the create_volume() call) has the following set of permissions-

`"kms:Decrypt", "kms:ReEncrypt*", "kms:GenerateDataKey*", "kms:ListGrants", "kms:RevokeGrant", "kms:Encrypt", "kms:DescribeKey"`

Since you are trying to encrypt the volumes you need to make sure your code is able to access the CMK that you intend to use.